# Sending live video frame over network in python opencv

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm trying to send live video frame that I catch with my camera to a server and process them. I'm usig opencv for image processing and python for the language. Here is my code

**`client_cv.py`**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    print sys.getsizeof(frame)
    print frame
    clientsocket.send(pickle.dumps(frame))
```

**`server_cv.py`**

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
HOST=''
PORT=8089

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'

s.bind((HOST,PORT))
print 'Socket bind complete'
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'

conn,addr=s.accept()

while True:
    data=conn.recv(80)
    print sys.getsizeof(data)
    frame=pickle.loads(data)
    print frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

This code gives me end of file error, which is logical because the data always keep coming to the server and pickle doesn't know when to finish. My search on the internet made me use pickle but it doesn't work so far.

**Note**: I set `conn.recv` to 80 because that's the number I get when I say `print sys.getsizeof(frame)`.

Comment: rather use cv2.imencode() / cv2.imdecode() than pickle

Comment: Anyone who's tried this for livestream, is it viable to send it to the server? Or is it better to process the frame locally? For example, continuous face_recognition, a ping should be made as soon as the face is detected?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Few things:

- use `sendall` instead of `send` since you're not guaranteed everything will be sent in one go
- `pickle` is ok for data serialization but you have to make a protocol of
  you own for the messages you exchange between the client and the server, this
  way you can know in advance the amount of data to read for unpickling (see
  below)
- for `recv` you will get better performance if you receive big chunks, so replace 80 by 4096 or even more
- beware of `sys.getsizeof`: it returns the size of the object in memory, which is not
  the same as the size (length) of the bytes to send over the network ; for a
  Python string the two values are not the same at all
- be mindful of the size of the frame you are sending. Code below supports a frame up to 65535. Change "H" to "L" if you have a larger frame.

A protocol example:

client_cv.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct ### new code
cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))
while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    data = pickle.dumps(frame) ### new code
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("H", len(data))+data) ### new code
```

server_cv.py

```
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct ## new

HOST=''
PORT=8089

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST,PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn,addr=s.accept()

### new
data = ""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("H") 
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("H", packed_msg_size)[0]
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]
    ###

    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
    print frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
```

You can probably optimize all this a lot (less copying, using the buffer interface, etc) but at least you can get the idea.

Comment: I tried your code without any change at got the following error:                File "stack_client.py", line 13, in <module>
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("H", len(data))+data) ### new code
struct.error: ushort format requires 0 <= number <= USHRT_MAX

Comment: How much is len(data)? Try with L instead of H - H means unsigned short

Comment: Yes, It worked out when I changed H to L. Now the server side prints the array when I say print frame. The last problem is to fix cv2.imread('frame',frame) because it doesn't open any window and also doesn't give any error but I think I can fix it by myself. Thanks for your help it is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi @mguijarr i am trying to use your code but i'am getting an empty non respond window !  atayenel can you give the code you use if you succed to make it run please

Comment: this code is not working with Python 3 although its perfectly working with python 2.

Comment: yes, I have a python 3 version whch is slightly different from this code.

Comment: @Saikat I would be happy to add the Python 3 version to the answer or at least post your own answer for Python 3 to help others :)

Comment: Could you please post the Python 3 Version?

Comment: @RohanSawant I posted the Python 3 version below

Comment: could you please let me know how I can open the show window on the browser instead of  cv2.imshow('frame',frame)? @mguijarr

Comment: @SajjadRostami if you want you can study the code [here](https://github.com/mguijarr/demo_pyugg) (beware it is Python 2): it shows how to use the Bottle Python module to make a Single Page Application that runs on the browser with live video streaming using old tricks (multipart messages... Nothing fancy like websockets or webrtc)

Comment: Anyone who's tried this for livestream, is it viable to send it to the server? Or is it better to process the frame locally? For example, continuous face_recognition, a ping should be made as soon as the face is detected?

Answer (score 18):

After months of searching the internet, this is what I came up with, I have neatly packaged it into classes, with unit tests and documentation as [SmoothStream](https://github.com/CT83/SmoothStream/) check it out, it was the only simple and working version of streaming I could find anywhere.

I used this code and wrapped mine around it.

Viewer.py

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

while True:
    try:
        frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
        img = base64.b64decode(frame)
        npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
        source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
        cv2.imshow("Stream", source)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Streamer.py

```
import base64
import cv2
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # init the camera

while True:
    try:
        grabbed, frame = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
        encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
        footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Comment: Encoding the jpeg data as base64 multiplies the payload by 3 or so... Why don't you send the raw jpeg binary?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea how I would go about doing that, could you please, show me how? Convert the numpy array to string?

Comment: The thing our friend @mguijarr noticed is about the overhead you're having for encoding twice your frame with imencode + b64encode.
If you concern about performance and your streamer only needs to send the image to the client/viewer. I'd recommend you to send the frame raw data directly.
Then, on your client/viewer side, you only need to imencode the raw frame to jpeg as you wish.

Comment: I get "TypeError: Incorrect padding" during b64decode .

Answer (score 11):

I changed the code from @mguijarr to work with Python 3. Changes made to the code:

- `data` is now a [byte literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6269765/what-does-the-b-character-do-in-front-of-a-string-literal) instead of a string literal
- Changed "H" to "L" to send larger frame sizes. Based on [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html), we can now send frames of size 2^32 instead of just 2^16.

Server.py

```
import pickle
import socket
import struct

import cv2

HOST = ''
PORT = 8089

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print('Socket created')

s.bind((HOST, PORT))
print('Socket bind complete')
s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

conn, addr = s.accept()

data = b'' ### CHANGED
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") ### CHANGED

while True:

    # Retrieve message size
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0] ### CHANGED

    # Retrieve all data based on message size
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)

    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]

    # Extract frame
    frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)

    # Display
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Client.py

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    # Serialize frame
    data = pickle.dumps(frame)

    # Send message length first
    message_size = struct.pack("L", len(data)) ### CHANGED

    # Then data
    clientsocket.sendall(message_size + data)
```

Comment: I would argue that this is a much better way of doing things! If you would be kind enough to make a PR to https://github.com/CT83/SmoothStream/ many others would benefit from this as well.

Comment: Currently, I seem to have unecessary dependencies on ZeroMQ, your code solves that problem!

Comment: Beware that 'L' is not the same all architectures and if you want to make a Raspberry Pi send messages to a PC, you may use '=L' instead.

Comment: Thank you @Charles-ÉdouardCoste , this was life saver, I had no clue why the data size was different when I was trying to send from Raspberry Pi  unless I read your comment. Thanks a ton man.

Answer (score 3):

I'm kind of late but my powerful & threaded [*VidGear*](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear) Video Processing python library now provide [**NetGear API**](https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/NetGear), which is exclusively designed to transfer video frames synchronously between interconnecting systems over the network in real-time. Here's an example:

#### A. Server End:(Bare-Minimum example)

Open your favorite terminal and execute the following python code:

**Note:** *You can end streaming anytime on both server and client side by pressing [Ctrl+c] on your keyboard on server end!*

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import VideoGear
from vidgear.gears import NetGear

stream = VideoGear(source='test.mp4').start() #Open any video stream
server = NetGear() #Define netgear server with default settings

# infinite loop until [Ctrl+C] is pressed
while True:
    try: 
        frame = stream.read()
        # read frames

        # check if frame is None
        if frame is None:
            #if True break the infinite loop
            break

        # do something with frame here

        # send frame to server
        server.send(frame)
    
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        #break the infinite loop
        break

# safely close video stream
stream.stop()
# safely close server
server.close()
```

#### B. Client End:(Bare-Minimum example)

Then open another terminal on the same system and execute the following python code and see the output:

```py
# import libraries
from vidgear.gears import NetGear
import cv2

#define netgear client with `receive_mode = True` and default settings
client = NetGear(receive_mode = True)

# infinite loop
while True:
    # receive frames from network
    frame = client.recv()

    # check if frame is None
    if frame is None:
        #if True break the infinite loop
        break

    # do something with frame here

    # Show output window
    cv2.imshow("Output Frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    # check for 'q' key-press
    if key == ord("q"):
        #if 'q' key-pressed break out
        break

# close output window
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
# safely close client
client.close()
```

**More advanced usage and related docs can be found here:** https://github.com/abhiTronix/vidgear/wiki/NetGear

Comment: Thanks for implementing such a powerful library. I want to receive a response after sending the frame to server. can you please provide code snippets to get a response from the server. Thanks

Comment: @Balavenkatesh already replied you on our [gitter](https://gitter.im/vidgear/community) community channel.

Comment: Thanks. i got it.

Answer (score 2):

as @Rohan Sawant said i used zmq library without using base64 encoding. here is the new code

> Streamer.py

```
import base64
import cv2
import zmq
import numpy as np
import time

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://192.168.1.3:5555')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # init the camera

while True:
        try:
                grabbed, frame = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
                frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
                encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
                footage_socket.send(buffer)


        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                camera.release()
                cv2.destroyAllWindows()
                break
```

> Viewer.py

```
import cv2
import zmq
import base64
import numpy as np

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
footage_socket.bind('tcp://*:5555')
footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

while True:
    try:
        frame = footage_socket.recv()
        npimg = np.frombuffer(frame, dtype=np.uint8)
        #npimg = npimg.reshape(480,640,3)
        source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)
        cv2.imshow("Stream", source)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made it to work on my MacOS.

I used the code from @mguijarr and changed the struct.pack from "H" to "L".

```py
# Server.py:
import socket
import sys
import cv2
import pickle
import numpy as np
import struct ## new


HOST=''
PORT=8089
    
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print 'Socket created'
    
s.bind((HOST,PORT))
print 'Socket bind complete'
s.listen(10)
print 'Socket now listening'
    
conn,addr=s.accept()
    
# new
data = ""
payload_size = struct.calcsize("L") 
while True:
    while len(data) < payload_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
    data = data[payload_size:]
    msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]
    while len(data) < msg_size:
        data += conn.recv(4096)
    frame_data = data[:msg_size]
    data = data[msg_size:]
    
    
    frame=pickle.loads(frame_data)
    print frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        
    key = cv2.waitKey(10)
    if (key == 27) or (key == 113):
        break
    
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```py
# Client.py
import cv2
import numpy as np
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct ### new code


cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))

while True:
    ret,frame=cap.read()
    data = pickle.dumps(frame) ### new code
    clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data))+data) ### new code
```

Answer (score 1):

Recently I publish imagiz package for Fast and none blocking live video streaming over network with OpenCV and ZMQ.

https://pypi.org/project/imagiz/

Client :

```
import imagiz
import cv2


client=imagiz.Client("cc1",server_ip="localhost")
vid=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
encode_param = [int(cv2.IMWRITE_JPEG_QUALITY), 90]

while True:
    r,frame=vid.read()
    if r:
        r, image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame, encode_param)
        client.send(image)
    else:
        break
```

Server :

```
import imagiz
import cv2

server=imagiz.Server()
while True:
    message=server.recive()
    frame=cv2.imdecode(message.image,1)
    cv2.imshow("",frame)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```