# How to integrating OpenCV to website for processing live-feed for detection

Tags: python, opencv, flask, server, real-time

Currently working on an OpenCV for real time detection and deploying the model on Flask, on local-host.

Main Goal : To integrate the model on a website so that whenever the site is being visited, visitor's live feed from his/her cam can be used and processed through OpenCV and would give output.

Problem : Have completed the part where we are able to run the flask app on local-host ( the feed being displayed on HTML page), but now :

1) How to integrate the model to the main website.[ like currently being local-host, webcam is directly accessible, but what to do in case of website deployment. ]

2) How to put the associated dependencies on the server. [ like required libraries, packages, which were imported for usage in main file. ]

**Pointing out the required resources along with tips/directions to start from will be really helpful.**

Links that being referred before asking question here:

0. [link0](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/09/02/opencv-stream-video-to-web-browser-html-page/)
1. [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44506323/how-to-send-webcam-video-to-amazon-aws-ec2-instance)
2. [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988033/sending-live-video-frame-over-network-in-python-opencv)

Thank you

Comment: You are gonna need to constrain your definition of “real-time processing” here. Depending on the size of the frames and the computational load of your operations, expect heavy and slow data traffic over the web architecture.

Comment: @eldesgraciado and how to inspect and plan accordingly, as currently i don't have much background with web-development along with proper backend