# Video is freezed while video streaming

Tags: javascript, python-2.7, sockets, opencv, video-streaming

I find the following code for streaming video over a socket in python2.7. When I run it, the video will be freeze at the beginning in the server-side (It shows the video in a web browser). I debugged the code and understood that in the streamer.py, the third while loop condition creates an infinite loop because of the condition while len(data) < msg_size: is always satisfied. In other words, len(data) is always less than msg_size.So, the streamer.py does not return the image to the server.py. Could anyone help me to solve this issue?

The server.py is:

```py
     from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
     from streamer import Streamer
     app = Flask(__name__)

     def gen():
       streamer = Streamer('localhost', 8089)
       streamer.start()

       while True:
         if streamer.client_connected():
             yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + 
             streamer.get_jpeg() + b'\r\n\r\n')

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
       return render_template('index.html')

    @app.route('/video_feed')
    def video_feed():
        return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; 
        boundary=frame')

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      app.run(host='localhost', threaded=True)
```

The streamer.py is:

```
import threading
import socket
import struct
import StringIO
import json
import numpy

class Streamer (threading.Thread):
  def __init__(self, hostname, port):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    self.hostname = hostname
    self.port = port
    self.connected = False
    self.jpeg = None

  def run(self):

    self.isRunning = True

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print 'Socket created'

    s.bind((self.hostname, self.port))
    print 'Socket bind complete'

    data = ""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("L")

    s.listen(10)
    print 'Socket now listening'

    while self.isRunning:

      conn, addr = s.accept()
      print 'while 1...'

      while True:

        data = conn.recv(4096)

        print 'while 2...'
        if data:
          packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
          data = data[payload_size:]
          msg_size = struct.unpack("L", packed_msg_size)[0]

          while len(data) < msg_size:# the infinite loop is here(my problem)!
            data += conn.recv(4096)
            print ("lenght of data is " , len(data) )
            print ("message size is  " ,  msg_size )

          frame_data = data[:msg_size]
          #frame_data = data[:len(data)]
          memfile = StringIO.StringIO()
          memfile.write(json.loads(frame_data).encode('latin-1'))
          memfile.seek(0)
          frame = numpy.load(memfile)

          ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
          self.jpeg = jpeg

          self.connected = True
          print 'recieving...'

        else:
          conn.close()
          self.connected = False
          print 'connected=false...'
          break

    self.connected = False

  def stop(self):
    self.isRunning = False

  def client_connected(self):
    return self.connected

  def get_jpeg(self):
    return self.jpeg.tobytes()
```

Client.py is:

```
import socket
import sys
import pickle
import struct
import StringIO
import json
import time

cap=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
clientsocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientsocket.connect(('localhost',8089))

while(cap.isOpened()):
  ret,frame=cap.read()

  memfile = StringIO.StringIO()
  np.save(memfile, fravidme)
  memfile.seek(0)
  data = json.dumps(memfile.read().decode('latin-1'))

  clientsocket.sendall(struct.pack("L", len(data))+data)
  if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break

cap.release()
```

I want to show the video captured by my laptop's camera on a client machine in the same network. I expect video stream but in the browser, I just watch an image and it does not update continuously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I analyzed this code I noticed that the default implementation for sending OpenCV frames over the network was not working. I decided to replace it with ZeroMQ implementation I have used [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51718862/7127317). You can check out the linked question for a deeper explanation of how the streaming works. I have neatly packaged it into classes, with unit tests and documentation as [SmoothStream](https://github.com/CT83/SmoothStream) check it out too.

Coming back to the question, here is the working code.

client.py

```
import base64
import cv2
import zmq

context = zmq.Context()
footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
footage_socket.connect('tcp://localhost:5555')

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)  # init the camera

while True:
    try:
        grabbed, frame = camera.read()  # grab the current frame
        frame = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480))  # resize the frame
        encoded, buffer = cv2.imencode('.jpg', frame)
        jpg_as_text = base64.b64encode(buffer)
        footage_socket.send(jpg_as_text)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        camera.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

server.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Response
from streamer import Streamer

app = Flask(__name__)


def gen():
    streamer = Streamer('*', 5555)
    streamer.start()

    while True:
        if streamer.client_connected():
            yield (b'--frame\r\n'b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + streamer.get_jpeg() + b'\r\n\r\n')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/video_feed')
def video_feed():
    return Response(gen(), mimetype='multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=frame')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='localhost', threaded=True)
```

streamer.py

```
import base64
import threading

import cv2
import numpy as np
import zmq


class Streamer(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, hostname, port):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

        self.hostname = hostname
        self.port = port
        self.connected = False
        self.jpeg = None

    def run(self):

        self.isRunning = True

        context = zmq.Context()
        footage_socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
        footage_socket.bind('tcp://{}:{}'.format(self.hostname, self.port))
        footage_socket.setsockopt_string(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, np.unicode(''))

        while self.isRunning:
            frame = footage_socket.recv_string()
            img = base64.b64decode(frame)
            npimg = np.fromstring(img, dtype=np.uint8)
            source = cv2.imdecode(npimg, 1)

            ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', source)
            self.jpeg = jpeg

            self.connected = True

        self.connected = False

    def stop(self):
        self.isRunning = False

    def client_connected(self):
        return self.connected

    def get_jpeg(self):
        return self.jpeg.tobytes()
```

> I understand that copy-pasting entire .py files are probably not the best way to post an answer here, but this is a complex question with a lot of moving parts and I honestly could not think of a better way to help the OP.